# Can't select loops, ALT+Left Mouse moves View

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, mouse

I can't select multiple loops, because whenever I hit "Alt+Left Mouse" or "Alt+Shift+Left Mouse", it moves the view instead of selecting loops.

I've been trying to solve this by deleting all double instances of "Alt+left Mouse" in my keymapping, but for now nothing else but "Select Loop" is bind to this, and the problem is still there. I ask this because I have no idea why Alt+left Mouse affects the view and I don't know as well where is the option to disable this?

Here's a screencap of what appears when I press (left) Alt on my keyboard:
[image: Screencap]

Thanks in advance for any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

For those having the same issue: I have a real 3 button mouse, but Blender was set to "Emulate a 3 button mouse" (In Edit>Preferences>Input>"Emulate 3 Button Mouse" must be unchecked).

In hope that it helps anyone having the same issue.